# android - java get id of the item just clicked without set "onClick" to the item

Tags: java, android-studio, click

How do I get an item id when I click on it without setting an "onClick" event in the xmk file?

I tried that:

```
private View.OnClickListener globalClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int clickedPosition = (int) v.getTag();
                // do something with position
            }
        }
```

But i don't understand how to use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hello!
Rebuild the method as follows:**

```
    private View.OnClickListener globalClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                
            }
}
```

Well, to get the target ID that you click, it is better to first define the attribute `android:tag="target_id"` in the XML file, and then access it within the called method when the target is clicked, using the `v.getTag()`. Of course, you can also get the clicked ID via `v.getId()` without doing so. You can check the ID from:
use `if (v.getTag () == R.id.target_id)`, or parse it as follows:

```
String viewID = getResources (). GetResourceName (v.getId ())
```

Comment: Do you mean several items or buttons from a list or collection? I haven't tried it yet, but I think when you use the "getId()" method, the unique ID of the clicked object returns, and when you use the "getTag()" method, each of the objects is a subset of a parent object. When clicked, the parent tag defined in the xml file will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

Your code creates a listener without actually attaching it to anything, so it never receives click events. If you have, for example, a button that you want to respond to clicks, you can register your listener with it like so:

```
button.setOnClickListener(globalClickListener);
```